# Problem with a node.js recursive function (with pupeeter) - var not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a program with pupeteer that retrieves the list of button ids and their names.

I want to loop through these buttons then click on them and retrieve the ids and names...

So I created a recursive function which, with a list as input, allows you to browse and click.

Here is my code:

```
  return Array.isArray(a) &&
    Array.isArray(b) &&
    a.length === b.length &&
    a.every((val, index) => val === b[index]);
}

async function parcourt(liste, previousListe, path, page) {
                    console.log(liste)

 for (const bouton of liste) {
    if(!arrayEquals(liste, previousListe)){
        const id = await page.evaluate(el => el.id, bouton);
        const titres = await bouton.$$('div[class^="Cell_title"]')
        const titre = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, titres[0]);
        var Newpath = path + "/" + titre
        console.log(Newpath + " : " + id)
        await bouton.click()
        var Newliste = await page.$$('div[id^="catalog-"]')
        parcourt(await NewListe,liste,await Newpath,page)
    }
    return 0
 }
}



const getData = async () => {
  // 1 - Créer une instance de navigateur
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  // 2 - Naviguer jusqu'à l'URL cible
await page.goto("xxxxxxx")
const liste = await page.$$('div[id^="catalog-"]')
parcourt(liste, [], '',page)

}

// Appel de la fonction getData() et affichage des données
getData().then(value => {
  console.log(value)
})
```

I have this error message : ReferenceError: NewListe is not defined
at parcourt

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Please review [ask] - your question is lacking several key details you'll need to provide in order to get any semblance of helpful information in return.

Comment: i add the message error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo. You initialize the variable `Newliste` with a lowercase 'l' but try to access `NewListe` with a capital 'L'.

This should work:

```js
var NewListe = await page.$$('div[id^="catalog-"]')
parcourt(await NewListe,liste,await Newpath,page)
```

Comment: Thanks ! rookie mistake
But thanks verry much :)

Comment: @Jérémy No worries, we have all been there!